# How to parse JSON with a list of lists?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a "complicated" JSON string that is returned to me by an API.

It looks like this:

```json
{
  "data":[
    ["Distance to last strike","23.0","miles"],
    ["Time of last strike","1/14/2022 9:23:42 AM",""],
    ["Number of strikes today","1",""]
  ]
}
```

While the end goal will be to extract the distance, date/time, as well as count, for right now I am just trying to successfully get the distance.

My python script is:

```
import requests
import json
response_API = requests.get('http://localhost:8998/api/extra/lightning.json')
data = response_API.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
value = parse_json['Distance to last strike']
print(value)
```

This does not work. If I change the `value` line to

```
value = parse_json['data']
```

then the entire string I listed above is returned.

I am hoping it's just a simple formatting issue. Suggestions?

Comment: Trying to access an dict/list item is not parsing. And `parse_json['data']` returns a list not a string.

Comment: Fair enough.  This is why I asked the question.  As I said, I am new to this so I am trying to understand it all.

Comment: Two quick points: 1) `requests` has JSON support built in; just read `response_API.json` instead of `response_API.text`. 2) It *does not matter* that you got the data by parsing JSON. It is *just* a structure of nested dictionaries and/or lists, and you interact with it *just like you would* if you had gotten that structure in *any other way*. And an observation: "then the entire string I listed above is returned." No, it is not, assuming that the input and code are actually as you describe. A *list* would be returned, containing 3 elements which are themselves lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object with a list of lists.  If you fetch

```
value = parse_json['data']
```

Then you will have a list containing three lists.  So:

```
print(value[0][1])
```

will print "23.0".

Comment: Thank you Tim.  How would I print the Date/Time value?  (I can extrapolate your answer to figure out how to print the final 'count' value)

Comment: @sbagnato Do you understand what `value[0][1]` means? It's accessing a list item by index. `value[0]` is accessing the 1st item of `data`, and then `[1]` accesses the 2nd item of `value[0]`. I recommend splitting it out into `distance = value[0]` and `distance[1]` to clearly see it. Once you understand that, you should be able to print out any value on that JSON.